# Time complexity for HashMap put/get inside for?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Suppose I have the following code fragment:

```
for(int i=0; i < n.length(); i++) {
    int aux = n[i];
    if(map.containsKey(aux)) {
        map.put(aux, map.get(aux)+1);
    } else {
        map.put(aux, 1);
    }
}
```

My map is a HashMap.
I know the for would be O(n) then map operations have O(1), however I have three map operations there (containsKey, put and get) so would that be O(3n) or still O(n)?? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(3N) and O(N) would be just considered O(N).

---

I guess, maybe `getOrDefault()` would be an option, if I'd correctly recall:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
    int aux = n[i];

    map.put(aux, map.getOrDefault(aux, 0) + 1);
}
```

and your time and memory complexity would be both O(N).

---

I think another more readable version would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
    int aux = n[i];

    map.put(aux, -~map.getOrDefault(aux, 0));
}
```

`-~x` is just a bitwise operation for `x + 1` (`-~x = x + 1`). However, you can use whichever you would be comfortable.

---

#### Thanks to [ciamej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821497/ciamej) in the comment!

Comment: O(3N) = O(N) by definition.

Comment: Well, it should be actually `map.put(aux, map.getOrDefault(aux, 0) + 1);`

Comment: Btw: I've just checked your profile. Wow! 1,645 answers, that's amazing! Keep it up! :)

Comment: You've certainly helped a lot of people! Those answers matter even if most of them get only a couple votes (or even zero).